# Crouch animation bug

Tags: lua, roblox

When I press Left ctrl and then press shift walking, give speed even when I'm squatting

When you press Left Ctrl and then try to execute by pressing shift, even while squatting, it gives no speed to the character(no speed function in squat animation)

```lua
local UIS = game:GetService('UserInputService');
local key = Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift
local ctrl = Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl
local pl = game.Players.LocalPlayer;
local char = script.Parent or pl.CharacterAdded:Wait();
 
local hum = char:WaitForChild('Humanoid');
 
local Move = 'rbxassetid://14908666655'
local Idle = 'rbxassetid://14908644962'
 
local Crouching = false;
local Holding = false;
 
local HoldCrouching = false;
 
local function ResetAnimation(boolean)
    if boolean then
        script.CrouchAnimation.AnimationId = Move
    else
        script.CrouchAnimation.AnimationId = Idle
    end
end
 
local function ChangeState(boolean)
    if boolean then  
        hum.WalkSpeed = 8
        
        hum:SetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping, false)
        
        local Anim = hum:LoadAnimation(script.CrouchAnimation)
        Anim:Play()
    else
        hum.WalkSpeed = 16
        
        hum:SetStateEnabled(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping, true)
        for _,i in ipairs(hum.Animator:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
            if i and i.Name == 'CrouchAnimation' then
                i:Stop()
            end
        end
    end
end
 
script:WaitForChild('CrouchAnimation').Changed:Connect(function()
    if Crouching then
        
        for _,i in ipairs(hum.Animator:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
            if i and i.Name == 'CrouchAnimation' then
                i:Stop()
            end
        end
        
        local Anim = hum:LoadAnimation(script.CrouchAnimation) 
        Anim:Play()
    else
        for _,i in ipairs(hum.Animator:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
            if i and i.Name == 'CrouchAnimation' then
                i:Stop()
            end
        end
    end
end)
 
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input, proc) 
    if proc then
        return;
    end
    if Input then
        if Input.KeyCode == ctrl then
            if not Crouching then
                Crouching = true;
                
                ChangeState(true)
                
            elseif Crouching and not Holding then
                Crouching = false;
                
                ChangeState(false)
                
            end
        end
    end
end)
 
 
 
UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(Input, proc)
    if proc then
        return;
    end
    if Input then
        if Input.KeyCode == ctrl then
            if Crouching and Holding then
                Crouching = false;
 
                ChangeState(false)
            end
        end
    end
end)
 
game:GetService('RunService').RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if Crouching then
        if hum.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 then
            ResetAnimation(true)
        else
            ResetAnimation(false)
        end
    end
end)
```

The code is working properly, but I was wondering how to solve this little bug of running while squatting